# Fastest way iterate over 2 dataframes to find point in polygon

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes, one contains point coordinates and the other contains polygon boundaries (zones).
What is the fastest way to iterate over the list of points and count how many points there are in each polygon?

Below is my current implementation:

```
    for index, hotspot in hotspots.iterrows():
        for index, zone in zones.iterrows():
            polygon = shapely.wkt.loads(zone['the_geom'])
            point = shapely.wkt.loads(hotspot['the_geom'])
            if polygon.contains(point) == True:
                zonesNum[zone["OBJECTID"]] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually used "apply", it runs 13 times faster that way:

```
zones.apply(lambda row: row['polygon'].contains(point), axis=1)
```